# ListBox обновляется только при скроле мыши

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Есть такой ListBox:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectsList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ProjectsListValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="334" Margin="10,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

В какой-то момент я обновляю список, я делаю ProjectsList.Clear(), а после заново заполняю его

Так вот, после того как я его обновил в форме он не меняется, но я заметил, что ListBox выгружает новый список из ProjectsList каждый раз, когда я прокручиваю мышку в нем

Comment: Попробуйте у ListBox установить свойство `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"`

Comment: ProjectsList какого типа? ObservableCollection?

Comment: тип List<ProjectsListItem>

Comment: VirtualizingPanel не помогло